# Choose 3 points A, B and C in a circle O

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

I have to get $p$,$q$ and $r$.

$p$ = the probability of triangle $ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle

$q$ = the probability of triangle $ABC$ is a right-angled triangle

$r$ = the probability of triangle $ABC$ is an obtuse-angled triangle.

I have an idea that the diameter of O is important in determining the angle. But I cannot get exact $p$,$q$ and $r$.

Please help.

Comment: Using polar coordinates may help you.

Comment: But I cannot use polar coordinate since this course is not handlinh that concepts...

Comment: Hint: try to fix $A$ and $B$ and see how $C$ determines what the triangle is.

Comment: If AB is the diameter of O then no matter c's position, It is a right-angled triangle.

Comment: What if AB is not the diameter of O? You're getting there.

Comment: That is the difficulty... I think the diameter is the max of the length AB

Comment: Yes, it is. You're right.

Comment: This makes me confused.  I think whether the angle is acute or obtuse , It has nothing to do with the length of AB.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hint: Given $A$ and $B$ as in the picture above,

1. $\triangle ABC$ is acute-angled only if $C$ lies in the red arc, which has probability $\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$.
2. $\triangle ABC$ is right-angled only if $C$ is either $A^\prime$ or $B^\prime$, which has probability $0$.
3. $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse-angled otherwise, which has probability $1-\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}$.

Now, of course $p$, $q$, and $r$ should not depend on $\alpha$, so how do we compute those?

Comment: I don't know why but I think probability of $\triangle{ABC}$ being right-angled $\rightarrow 0$ instead of being $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability $q$ of getting a right angled triangle $\to 0,$
since $2$ of the $3$ points need to be *exactly* on the diameter.

For obtuse and acute angled triangles:

Choose $3$ random points on the circumference, draw diametral lines, and randomly choose a pole of each. Any 3 *consecutive* points necessarily lie in the same semicircle, and will form an *obtuse* angled triangle. There are $6$ such combos (starting from $1$ through $6$) against a total of $2^3 = 8$,
thus $r = \dfrac68 = \dfrac34$,
and $p = 1-r = \dfrac14$